# Dismiss autocorrect suggestion without space+backspace+space

Tags: keyboard, 7.0-nougat, auto-correct

Sometimes when I'm typing a unique word or proper noun on my phone, Google recommends for it to be autocorrected (I can tell because the word itself is underlined, and out of the suggested replacement words, the middle one is in **bold**). If I hit `space` to proceed to the next word, the underlined word (which I don't want changed) is replaced by the **bold** recommended word. This can be undone by hitting `backspace` (which reverts the word to what I had originally typed) and then `space` again (at which point it doesn't attempt to autocorrect).

Is there anyway to keep my word, as originally typed, without having to hit `space`+`backspace`+`space`? On Gboard for my iPhone it will *always* have my word as currently spelled as a suggested word that I can just touch to maintain. Is there a way to enable this for my Android?

Answer (score 0):

Install a different keyboard like hackerskeyboard.